# Uploading file from file object with PyCurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I'm attempting to upload a file like this:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()

values = [
     ("name", "tom"),
     ("image", (pycurl.FORM_FILE, "tom.png"))
]

c.setopt(c.URL, "http://upload.com/submit")
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, values)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

This works fine.  However, this only works if the file is local.  If I was to fetch the image such that:

```
import urllib2
resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://upload.com/people/tom.png")
```

How would I pass resp.fp as a file object instead of writing it to a file and passing the filename?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be possible in perfect situations to basically connect the two streams, but it wouldn't be a very robust solution.  There are a bunch of ugly boundary conditions:

- The response socket might still be
  receiving data, and/or be stalled,
  thus causing you to starve out and
  break the POST (because PycURL is not
  expecting to have to wait for data
  beyond the current end of the
  "file").
- The response might reset, and then you don't have the complete file, but you've already POSTed a bunch of data - what to do in this case?
- The file you're fetching with urllib might be chunked-encoded, so you need to perform some operations on the MIME headers for reassembly - you can't just blindly forward the data.
- You don't necessarily know how big the file you're getting is, so it's hard to provide the proper content-length on the POST, so then you have to write chunked.
- Probably a bunch of other problems I can't think of off the top of my head...

You'll be much better off writing the file to disk temporarily and then POSTing it once you know you have the whole thing.

If you did want to do this, the best way would probably be to implement your own file-like object which would manage the bridge between the two connections (could properly buffer, handle decoding, etc.).

EDIT:

Based on the comment you left - absolutely - you just need to setopt `READFUNCTION`.  Check out the file_upload example at:

http://pycurl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pycurl/pycurl/examples/file_upload.py?revision=1.5&view=markup

It does exactly this by making a tiny wrapper on a file object with a callback to read the data from it, or alternatively if you don't need to do any processing, you can literally set the `READFUNCTION` callback to be `fp.read`.

Comment: That probably wasn't the best example because it's not exactly how I was doing things.  My point was that the file content is already available via a file object so I wanted to know if there was an alternative way to pass that file handle to PyCurl instead of passing a filename.

Comment: @Tom: See my edited response - what you're trying to do is actually really trivial if you already have a file object that is otherwise robust.